Local Sections of Dualizing Sheaf
Let $f : C\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$ be a proper connected nodal curve over algebraically closed field $k$ and $\omega_C$ its dualizing sheaf. Let $\nu : C'\rightarrow C$ be the normalization map.
Question: How to determine that the local sections of $\omega_C$ can be described in terms of residues of preimages, where $\nu $ fails to be an iso, ie that for open $U \subset C$ we have characterization
$$\omega_{C}(U) = \{r \in \Omega^1_{C'/k}(Q_1+Q_2)(\nu^{-1}(U)) : \text{res}_{Q_1}w + \text{res}_{Q_2}w = 0\}$$
where $Q_1,Q_2$ run over all distinct pairs of points in $C'$ which map to a same point $P \in C$, ie where $\nu$ is not a iso and $\Omega_{C'/k}$ sheaf of Kähler differentials which coincides with $\omega_{C'}$ is case $C'$ smooth. But as we work over alg closed field $k$, smooth and regular is the same and normal curve is regular. Note stable curve over alg closed base field implies that its singularities are at most nodal & finitely many.
Motivation: This seems to be well known, see here. I would like to have reference or sketch indicating which arguments go in.
